# regex expression in java using wildcards

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to use a regex expression with wild cards?  Specifically, I have a String phrase and another String target.  I would like to use the match method to find the first occurrence of the target in the phrase where the character before and after the target is anything other than a-z.

Updated:

Is there a way to use the String method matches() with the following regex:

```
"(?<![a-z])" + "hello" + "(?![a-z])";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the regex, `"(?<![a-z])" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + "(?![a-z])"`

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/A1GEHL/1) with phrase = "hello".

- `(?<![a-z])`: Negative lookbehind for `[a-z]`
- `(?![a-z])`: Negative lookahead for `[a-z]`

**Java Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String phrase = "hello";
        String regex = "(?<![a-z])" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + "(?![a-z])";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Stream.of(
                "hi hello world",
                "hihelloworld"
        ).forEach(s -> {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
            System.out.print(s + " => ");
            if(matcher.find()) {
                System.out.println("Match found");
            }else {
                System.out.println("No match found");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hi hello world => Match found
hihelloworld => No match found
```

In case you want the full-match, use the regex, `.*(?<![a-z]) + Pattern.quote(phrase) +(?![a-z]).*` as demonstrated at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/EjPQv3/1). The pattern, `.*` means any character any number of times. The rest of the patterns are already explained above. The presence of `.*` before and after the match will ensure covering the whole string.

**Java Demo:**

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        String phrase = "hello";
        String regex = ".*(?<![a-z])" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + "(?![a-z]).*";
        Stream.of(
                    "hi hello world", 
                    "hihelloworld"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + (s.matches(regex) ? "Match found" : "No match found")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
hi hello world => Match found
hihelloworld => No match found
```

Comment: It might be safer to escape the dynamic part.  `"(?<![a-z])" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + "(?![a-z])"`

Comment: is there a way to use the String method matches() with "(?<![a-z])" + "hello" + "(?![a-z])";

Comment: thank you.  could you possibly explain he regex:  ".*(?<![a-z])" + Pattern.quote(phrase) + "(?![a-z]).*";

Comment: @DCR - The pattern, `.*` means any character any number of times. The presence of `.*` before and after the match will ensure covering the whole string. If there is no match, nothing will be covered.

Comment: @Arvind Kumar Avinash is the following correct: the .* at the front end captures the entire string up to the target.  the .* at the backend captures the string from then end of the target to the end of the phrase.  then it essentially performs a nested loop and deletes a character in the front and tries to match , when the entire front piece is deleted it deletes a character from the backend and starts all over on the front end - keeps doing this to see if it can match